# unable to build nifi-assembly

Tags: apache, maven, apache-nifi

i'm running `mvn install` and also the suggested `mvn -T C2.0 clean install -Pinclude-grpc` from [the nifi quickstart page](https://nifi.apache.org/quickstart.html)

It seems to be some issue with 1.6.0 SNAPSHOT dependencies. Doing -U doesnt help out either.

i've started with a fresh repo a number of times and it always ends up failing. Here is the full  -X log

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 05:15 min (Wall Clock)
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-15T11:02:35+11:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/61M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project nifi-assembly: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.nifi:nifi-assembly:pom:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.nifi:nifi-framework-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-provenance-repository-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-ssl-context-service-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-distributed-cache-services-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-datadog-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-standard-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-update-attribute-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hadoop-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-0-8-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-0-9-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-0-10-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-0-11-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-1-0-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-confluent-platform-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-html-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-lookup-services-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-poi-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kite-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kudu-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-flume-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-dbcp-service-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-mongodb-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-mongodb-services-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-solr-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-social-media-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hl7-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-ccda-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-language-translation-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-enrich-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-aws-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-ambari-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-ignite-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-rethinkdb-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-avro-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-media-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-couchbase-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hbase-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-riemann-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hbase_1_1_2-client-service-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-azure-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-scripting-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-groovyx-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-elasticsearch-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-elasticsearch-5-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-lumberjack-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-beats-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-cybersecurity-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-email-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-amqp-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-splunk-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-jms-processors-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-cassandra-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-spring-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-registry-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hive-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-site-to-site-reporting-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-record-serialization-services-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-mqtt-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-snmp-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-evtx-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-slack-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-windows-event-log-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-websocket-services-api-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-websocket-services-jetty-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-websocket-processors-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-tcp-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-gcp-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-stateful-analysis-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-cdc-mysql-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-parquet-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hwx-schema-registry-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-redis-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-metrics-reporting-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-livy-controller-service-api-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-livy-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-druid-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-grpc-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.apache.nifi:nifi-framework-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT in apache.snapshots (https://repository.apache.org/snapshots) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project nifi-assembly: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.nifi:nifi-assembly:pom:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.nifi:nifi-framework-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-provenance-repository-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-ssl-context-service-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-distributed-cache-services-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-datadog-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-standard-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-update-attribute-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hadoop-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-0-8-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-0-9-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-0-10-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-0-11-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-1-0-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-confluent-platform-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-html-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-lookup-services-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-poi-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kite-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kudu-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-flume-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-dbcp-service-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-mongodb-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-mongodb-services-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-solr-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-social-media-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hl7-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-ccda-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-language-translation-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-enrich-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-aws-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-ambari-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-ignite-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-rethinkdb-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-avro-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-media-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-couchbase-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hbase-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-riemann-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hbase_1_1_2-client-service-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-azure-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-scripting-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-groovyx-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-elasticsearch-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-elasticsearch-5-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-lumberjack-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-beats-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-cybersecurity-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-email-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-amqp-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-splunk-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-jms-processors-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-cassandra-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-spring-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-registry-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hive-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-site-to-site-reporting-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-record-serialization-services-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-mqtt-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-snmp-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-evtx-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-slack-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-windows-event-log-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-websocket-services-api-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-websocket-services-jetty-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-websocket-processors-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-tcp-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-gcp-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-stateful-analysis-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-cdc-mysql-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-parquet-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hwx-schema-registry-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-redis-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-metrics-reporting-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-livy-controller-service-api-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-livy-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-druid-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-grpc-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.apache.nifi:nifi-framework-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT in apache.snapshots (https://repository.apache.org/snapshots)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:221)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:246)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:196)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.nifi:nifi-assembly:pom:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.nifi:nifi-framework-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-provenance-repository-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-ssl-context-service-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-distributed-cache-services-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-datadog-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-standard-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-update-attribute-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hadoop-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-0-8-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-0-9-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-0-10-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-0-11-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-1-0-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-confluent-platform-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-html-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-lookup-services-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-poi-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kite-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kudu-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-flume-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-dbcp-service-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-mongodb-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-mongodb-services-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-solr-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-social-media-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hl7-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-ccda-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-language-translation-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-enrich-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-aws-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-ambari-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-ignite-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-rethinkdb-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-avro-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-media-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-couchbase-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hbase-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-riemann-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hbase_1_1_2-client-service-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-azure-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-scripting-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-groovyx-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-elasticsearch-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-elasticsearch-5-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-lumberjack-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-beats-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-cybersecurity-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-email-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-amqp-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-splunk-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-jms-processors-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-cassandra-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-spring-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-registry-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hive-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-site-to-site-reporting-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-record-serialization-services-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-mqtt-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-snmp-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-evtx-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-slack-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-windows-event-log-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-websocket-services-api-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-websocket-services-jetty-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-websocket-processors-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-tcp-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-gcp-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-stateful-analysis-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-cdc-mysql-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-parquet-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hwx-schema-registry-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-redis-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-metrics-reporting-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-livy-controller-service-api-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-livy-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-druid-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-grpc-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.apache.nifi:nifi-framework-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT in apache.snapshots (https://repository.apache.org/snapshots)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:195)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.nifi:nifi-framework-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-provenance-repository-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-ssl-context-service-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-distributed-cache-services-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-datadog-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-standard-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-update-attribute-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hadoop-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-0-8-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-0-9-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-0-10-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-0-11-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-1-0-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-confluent-platform-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-html-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-lookup-services-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-poi-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kite-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kudu-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-flume-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-dbcp-service-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-mongodb-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-mongodb-services-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-solr-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-social-media-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hl7-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-ccda-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-language-translation-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-enrich-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-aws-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-ambari-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-ignite-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-rethinkdb-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-avro-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-media-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-couchbase-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hbase-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-riemann-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hbase_1_1_2-client-service-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-azure-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-scripting-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-groovyx-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-elasticsearch-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-elasticsearch-5-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-lumberjack-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-beats-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-cybersecurity-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-email-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-amqp-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-splunk-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-jms-processors-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-cassandra-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-spring-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-registry-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hive-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-site-to-site-reporting-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-record-serialization-services-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-mqtt-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-snmp-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-evtx-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-slack-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-windows-event-log-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-websocket-services-api-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-websocket-services-jetty-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-websocket-processors-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-tcp-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-gcp-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-stateful-analysis-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-cdc-mysql-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-parquet-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hwx-schema-registry-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-redis-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-metrics-reporting-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-livy-controller-service-api-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-livy-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-druid-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-grpc-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.apache.nifi:nifi-framework-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT in apache.snapshots (https://repository.apache.org/snapshots)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:202)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.nifi:nifi-framework-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-provenance-repository-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-ssl-context-service-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-distributed-cache-services-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-datadog-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-standard-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-update-attribute-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hadoop-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-0-8-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-0-9-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-0-10-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-0-11-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kafka-1-0-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-confluent-platform-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-html-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-lookup-services-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-poi-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kite-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-kudu-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-flume-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-dbcp-service-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-mongodb-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-mongodb-services-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-solr-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-social-media-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hl7-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-ccda-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-language-translation-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-enrich-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-aws-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-ambari-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-ignite-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-rethinkdb-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-avro-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-media-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-couchbase-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hbase-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-riemann-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hbase_1_1_2-client-service-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-azure-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-scripting-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-groovyx-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-elasticsearch-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-elasticsearch-5-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-lumberjack-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-beats-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-cybersecurity-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-email-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-amqp-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-splunk-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-jms-processors-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-cassandra-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-spring-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-registry-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hive-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-site-to-site-reporting-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-record-serialization-services-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-mqtt-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-snmp-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-evtx-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-slack-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-windows-event-log-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-websocket-services-api-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-websocket-services-jetty-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-websocket-processors-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-tcp-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-gcp-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-stateful-analysis-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-cdc-mysql-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-parquet-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-hwx-schema-registry-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-redis-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-metrics-reporting-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-livy-controller-service-api-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-livy-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-druid-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.nifi:nifi-grpc-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.apache.nifi:nifi-framework-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT in apache.snapshots (https://repository.apache.org/snapshots)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:338)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.apache.nifi:nifi-framework-nar:nar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT in apache.snapshots (https://repository.apache.org/snapshots)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    ... 3 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to clarify, are you running `mvn clean install` inside `nifi/` or `nifi/nifi-assembly/`? You need to run it at the top level in order to build each of the artifacts required for the eventual `nifi-assembly` module to succeed, because `*-SNAPSHOT` artifacts are not published to any Maven repository. If you were building with `1.5.0`, you could build only `nifi-assembly` because the component artifacts are available in a repository.

Comment: That's the ticket. I was using the [dev kickstart instructions](https://nifi.apache.org/quickstart.html) instead of just simply using [nifi download](https://nifi.apache.org/download.html). thats a day an a half down the drain..

Comment: We will try to clarify those instructions, but even there, it does say you have to build the whole codebase unless you are just replacing a single NAR.